# Python sklearn GaussianNB model.fit error

Tags: python, scikit-learn

On running the following code I am getting the below error, please help:

```
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
X_iris = iris.drop('species', axis=1)
y_iris = iris['species']
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
Xtrain, Xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(X_iris, y_iris, random_state=1)
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
model = GaussianNB() 
model.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)
```

> error is:
> **TypeError: _validate_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'**

Comment: I can't reproduce this. For me, your code executes without the error. Are you sure this is what you're executing? Maybe try it in a fresh virtual environment making sure that seaborn and sklearn and correctly installed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi The problem got resolved on restarting the Kernel and running the code again. Please excuse me for the delayed response. Thanks a lot.